# EulerEquations Error

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, variational-calculus

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]

Clear["Global`*"];
r1 = s1 {Sin[ϕ1[t]], -Cos[ϕ1[t]]};
r2 = r1 + s2 {Sin[ϕ2[t]], -Cos[ϕ2[t]]};

lagrangian = m1/2*D[r1, t]*D[r1, t] + m2/2*D[r2, t]*D[r2, t] - g*(m1 r1 + m2 r2);

eqs = EulerEquations[lagrangian, {ϕ1[t], ϕ2[t]}, {t, t}]
```

It shows an error:

> EulerEquations::args: EulerEquations takes a single integrand, a
>   function or list of functions, and a list of variables as input. >>

Why is this happening?

Comment: As pointed out by @KraZug, you simply forgot to do the dot product of the velocity vectors in the kinetic energy.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, EulerEquations takes only a single integrand, not a vector equation as you are trying to give it. Your Lagrangian looks like it should have two scalar terms, corresponding to kinetic energy terms, and a final potential term which is presumably supposed to be a scalar as well (but is currently a vector).

At the moment, you are multiplying component by component when you do `D[r1, t]*D[r1, t]`, rather than taking the dot product with `D[r1, t].D[r1, t]`. I suspect that gravity may well be supposed to be a vector not a scalar here, in the potential energy term.

Oh, and additionally you only need one instance of `t` in the end bracket. 
So this will work for instance, but I'm not entirely sure what your actual equations should be (particularly the gravity part).

```
EulerEquations[m1/2*D[r1, t].D[r1, t] + m2/2*D[r2, t].D[r2, t] 
    - {0,g}.(m1 r1 + m2 r2), {ϕ1[t], ϕ2[t]}, t]
```